# Calculating Probability of a Classification Model Prediction

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, bert-language-model, multiclass-classification

I have a classification task. The training data has 50 different labels. The customer wants to differentiate the low probability predictions, meaning that, I have to classify some test data as `Unclassified / Other` depending on the probability (certainty?) of the model.

When I test my code, the prediction result is a numpy array (I'm using different models, this is one is pre-trained BertTransformer). The prediction array doesn't contain probabilities such as in Keras `predict_proba()` method. These are numbers generated by prediction method of pretrained `BertTransformer` model.

```
[[-1.7862008  -0.7037363   0.09885322  1.5318055   2.1137428  -0.2216074
   0.18905772 -0.32575375  1.0748093  -0.06001111  0.01083148  0.47495762
   0.27160102  0.13852511 -0.68440574  0.6773654  -2.2712054  -0.2864312
  -0.8428862  -2.1132915  -1.0157436  -1.0340284  -0.35126117 -1.0333195
   9.149789   -0.21288703  0.11455813 -0.32903734  0.10503325 -0.3004114
  -1.3854568  -0.01692022 -0.4388664  -0.42163098 -0.09182278 -0.28269592
  -0.33082992 -1.147654   -0.6703184   0.33038092 -0.50087476  1.1643585
   0.96983343  1.3400391   1.0692116  -0.7623776  -0.6083422  -0.91371405
   0.10002492]]
```

I'm using `numpy.argmax()` to identify the correct label. The prediction works just fine. However, since these are not probabilities, I cannot compare the best result with a threshold value.

My question is, how can I define a threshold (say, 0.6), and then compare the probability of the argmax() element of the BertTransformer prediction array so that I can classify the prediction as "Other" if the probability is less than the threshold value?

**Edit 1:**

We are using 2 different models. One is Keras, and the other is BertTransformer. We have no problem in Keras since it gives the probabilities so I'm skipping Keras model.

The Bert model is pretrained. Here is how it is generated:

```
def model(self, data):
        number_of_categories = len(data['encoded_categories'].unique())
        model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
            "dbmdz/bert-base-turkish-128k-uncased",
            num_labels=number_of_categories,
            output_attentions=False,
            output_hidden_states=False,
        )

        # model.cuda()

        return model
```

The output given above is the result of `model.predict()` method. We compare both models, Bert is slightly ahead, therefore we know that the prediction works just fine. However, we are not sure what those numbers signify or represent.

Here is the [Bert documentation](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#bertforsequenceclassification).

Comment: Are you actually asking if it is *possible*, or if it is a valid/good idea? If the former, how can such a simple numeric manipulation *not* be possible? You may find the last part of own answer in [Tensorflow & Keras prediction threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62396675/tensorflow-keras-prediction-threshold) helpful.

Comment: @desertnaut Thanks. The example you provided is about Keras. I have two models: One is Keras and the other is Bert. I'm already using the same approach (predmax < threshold) in order to identify the "Unclassified" predictions in Keras model. However, as you can see in the example above, the Bert prediction output is not probabilities. There are negative and positive numbers and their sum is not 1.

Comment: This is not apparent from your question - please edit & update accordingly to clarify such crucial details; how exactly these numbers are produced would be also necessary. If you do not have probability outputs, how can we talk about any threshold?

Comment: @desertnaut Edited. That's what I'm trying to ask, actually. I don't know what these numbers represent, maybe they're a different kind of probability. Then, the question might turn back into "is it possible" rather than "valid/good idea".

Comment: What I meant is - what exactly is your `BertTransformer` model? Are you sure it is used for classification? Please post at least some link to its documentation or something.

Comment: @desertnaut I edited the question, and added model and documentation. Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BertForSequenceClassification` returns logits, i.e., the classification scores before normalization. You can normalize the scores by calling [`F.softmax(output, dim=-1)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#softmax) where `torch.nn.functional` was imported as `F`.

With thousands of labels, the normalization can be costly and you do not need it when you are only interested in argmax. This is probably why the models return the raw scores only.