# Get probabilities of multi-class tensorflow predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a model that predicts whether a certain instance belongs to either class 0, 1, 2, or 3.
In this case, class 3 is kind of the other class, containing the remaining instances that do not make sense to put in either 0, 1, or 2.

I am wondering if the following scenario is possible, and if not, what you would suggest implementing.

*In the ideal scenario I would like to do the following:*
Training a model on just the classes 0, 1, and 2. Checking the TensorFlow possibilities and assign class 3 only if the highest probability is under a certain threshold.
The problem with this is that it is not entirely clear to me how to get the TensorFlow probabilities. The reason why I would like to exclude class 3 is that it is kind of a garbage class that throws the model way off.

So I was wondering if it is possible to actually get the TensorFlow prediction probabilities per class? And if not, if there is a better way to handle this.

Thanks!

Comment: the output of any model is probabilities so yes it's possible

Comment: The problem is that those probabilities in the tensor are not between 0 and 1. So there is no way to use them directly with some sort of threshold, right?

Comment: If that's the case then you can get probabilities out of that tensor (which is usually called logits) using the [softmax](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax) function.

Comment: But here it says that you cannot use softmax in a multiclass classification right?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62396675/tensorflow-keras-prediction-threshold

Comment: multi-class yes, not multi-label. and softmax output isn't interpretable probabilities

Comment: Got it, thanks! So since this is a multi-class classification problem (each instance belongs to exactly one class), I can use softmas. What do you mean exactly with the second part of your answer? :)

Comment: Softmax forces the most likely category to have a high value (e.g. 0.9997) while the other categories have low values. This can't be interpreted as a very high confidence.